# Merging cells vertically

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got a table with a grouping. In this table, I want to call a subreport which displays a graph. The issue I'm facing is how to merge cells vertically, for example

Note: Everything below the Group are details and each Group has a page break

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Group
----------------------------------------------------------
Row1 | Column 1  Column 2  Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
Row2 | Column 1  Column 2  Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
Row3 | Column 1  Column 2  [Blank] [Blank] [Blank] [Blank]
Row4 | Column 1  Column 2  [Blank] [Blank] [Blank] [Blank]
Row5 | Column 1  Column 2  [Blank] [Blank] [Blank] [Blank]
Row6 | Column 1  Column 2  [Blank] [Blank] [Blank] [Blank]
```

So in the example above, I want to put a graph (subreport) in the section where it's all Blank.

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution but I've just made a single row and enlarged it instead of 3 rows (for Rows4-6) and instead of splitting my data into multiple rows, I've just placed them all on the same row